# MySQL Query Not Recognizing PHP Variable

Tags: php

I'm working on an SQL query that selects results based on a User ID number foreign key, and displays the result if there are any matching entries in the correlated table. When I try to use a PHP variable in my WHERE clause, it seems like the SQL query doesn't recognize a value at all, even though if I print the variable, there is a value there.

I've attempted changing the query with the `"'. $variable .'"` and `' . $variable . '`, but I still get the same result. Here is my code:

```
$usernum = intval($_SESSION['usernum']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM dinosaurs WHERE UserNum = '$usernum'";
```

When I enter the variable manually (for example `"SELECT * FROM dinosaurs WHERE UserNum = '6'";` it works, but when I attempt to run this query I get the following result:

```
SELECT * FROM dinosaurs WHERE UserNum = ''
returned 0 records.
```

It looks like the variable is just showing a blank value in the SQL statement? How would I get it to recognize the variable's value?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**
I figured it out! It was a dumb error where I was declaring the variable inside of a different function instead of globally so I moved the declaration to the correct function like this:

```
  // print_r($json);
  $usernum = intval($_SESSION['usernum']);
  }
```

So that just goes to show that I should pay more attention to my own code :)

Comment: Possibly your session isn't started.

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address immediately

Comment: @Qirel I have a script that checks for an existing session, and redirects if there isn't one started, and that's working okay! And when I run this: ` echo $usernum ` it returns the correct value.

Comment: use **parameterised statements** to solve all your query-building problems and protect your complete database from leaking by preventing **SQL injection attacks**. and check the *actual* content of `$usernum`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I ran `vardump($usernum)` and it returned **int(6)** which is what it should be. I'm using parameterized statements wherever I'm using user input in my SQL queries, but for this one I'm not using anything from a user input; is it necessary to use a parameterized statement in that scenario?

Comment: With any variable of any kind, ***always*** use a prepared statement. It'll save you some grief. That said, if you dump the variable *right before* the query-variable, and it isn't appearing within the query, then you're doing something else that you're not showing us. It's impossible for anything else to happen. See https://3v4l.org/rB6ub for demo

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and accept it, so others can see how you solved it :)

Comment: `$query = 'SELECT * FROM dinosaurs WHERE UserNum = '.(int) $usernum; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my original code:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['firstname']); 
    $usernum = intval($_SESSION['usernum']);
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
} else echo "<script> window.location.assign('uhoh.html'); </script>";
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'pretty_json.php';

submitQuery($conn, $json);

$conn->close();
```

I declared the `$usernum` variable in the original if statement, not globally. So when I tried to access it in the submitQuery function, it wasn't set to anything.

To solve it, I just declared the `$usernum` variable at the beginning of the submitQuery function.